# How to detect where request is coming from?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.4

Currently I have a Controller which controls the data sent and operation done.
For example, when I hit the home page, I would hit `Route::get('home', 'Controller@select');` which will select existing data and show it at that page.
On the same page, I have provided a form which user can input data into it and press the submit button which will hit this one `Route::post('home', 'Controller@insert');`, this works since it can differentiate between GET (from other page to home) and POST (from same page, but entered from the submit button form).

Now, I have the DELETE button on the very same page, but this one is that I'm using get, so if I still use `Route::get('home', 'Controller@delete');`, it won't work, since it the `Controller@select` will override it.

My question is that how do I detect where the request is coming from so I can prepare different operation for different request from the user?
I have a basic PHP knowledge, and I kinda want it similar to like `if(isset($_GET['delete']))`, do delete operation.

Another solution would be to move all the page to a different page, then redirect it to the home page but I still want to stick with the same page so it is convenient for the user to see the data flow easily.

Comment: in laravel, the first registered will override the rest. it's stored by url path and [http method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods).. the two answer below is pretty good for starter.

Comment: I removed [Solved] from the title. You can post your own answer accept one given or delete the question. In posting one/accepting, marks it as "solved".

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the route for example if you use Route::get('home', 'Controller@select'); it's mind you are pointing to Controller->select() method when you go to the url home for delete you should try something like `Route::get('home/delete', 'Controller@delete');` that mind when you go to the url home/delete will point to `Controller->delete()`

Comment: Isn't that pointing to a new page ? What I want is to point on the same page, every operation should point to the home page, instead of home/delete, home/update, home/insert

Comment: What if the problem of pointing to another page?
 You have to change something in request, to point it elsevere, either it is uri, or method.

Comment: look at this https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers

Answer (score 0):

You can either add "?delete=1"  and then check it in "select" method;

```
Route::post('delete', 'Controller@drop');
```

or you can make `Route::delete('home', 'Controller@drop')`;
But then you have to make delete request through ajax request like:

```
 $("#deleteButton").click(function() {
     $.ajax({
      method: "DELETE",
      url: "index.php",
     })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

When ever you are trying to perform delete operation you should set method as `DELETE`. However, by default we have only `GET` and `POST` methods. Laravel has nice wrap around(`method_field()`) for this to work. You simply have to add `_method` field to the form.

### Register Route

```
Route::destroy('home', 'Controller@destroy');
```

### By HTML form

```
<form method="POST" action="home">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    {!! method_field('DELETE') !!}
</form>
```

### By Ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: "home",
    method: "POST",
    data : { '_method' : 'DELETE', '_token' : 'YOUR CSRF TOKEN HERE'}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a dummy page from the form action like action="insert", then at the Route: Route::post('insert', 'Controller@insert'); and at the Controller is just doing the operation and return back the view to ('home').